# ArangoDB Foxx Microservices Getting Started tutorial: what is a working URI for this example?

Tags: arangodb, arangodb-foxx

The tutorial here [Getting started · ArangoDB v3.4.0 Documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Foxx/GettingStarted.html) uses this code:

```
// continued
router.post('/sum', function (req, res) {
const values = req.body.values;
res.send({
    result: values.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
    }, 0)
});
})
.body(joi.object({
values: joi.array().items(joi.number().required()).required()
}).required(), 'Values to add together.')
.response(joi.object({
result: joi.number().required()
}).required(), 'Sum of the input values.')
.summary('Add up numbers')
.description('Calculates the sum of an array of number values.');
```

What is an example of a URI that supplies the expected parameters (two numbers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your server instance runs on `localhost:8529` over HTTP, that the database is `_system` and the mount point of the Foxx service `/getting-started`, then the URL of the `/sum` endpoint is:

`http://localhost:8529/getting-started/sum`

Note that the database `_system` is special: It is the default, which means you don't have to specify it explicitly. The following URL is equivalent:

`http://localhost:8529/_db/_system/getting-started/sum`

Replace `_system` with the name of the actual database if the Foxx service is mounted in another one.

`/sum` is a POST route (`router.post(...)`) and the expected body (content/payload of the HTTP request) is described by the joi schema: A JSON object with the attribute name `values` and as attribute value a number array (one or more numbers).

With Curl, you can query the service like so:

`curl --data "{\"values\":[5,6]}" http://localhost:8529/getting-started/sum`

(The request method `-X POST` is inferred by Curl)

The response is a JSON object with an attribute key `result` and the calculated number as attribute value:

`{"result":11}`

If you try to access the URL in a browser instead, it will be a GET request (without payload) and fail with an HTTP error: *405 Method Not Allowed*

Comment: Thanks. Curl worked. How could this example be adapted to run in a browser, while keeping it super simple (on the level of this basic tutorial)? I suppose I should ask a new question, but I'm not sure exactly how to ask it. Why didn't this tutorial mention that this route would not work in a browser? Does everyone except me already know that? lol